# JQuery dialogs and Safari

Tags: jquery, css, styles

When using jquery dialogs in Safari (Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7))

I get horizontal lines appearing half way through the dialogs.  I've looked at the CSS and the generated HTML and I cannot see any reason for it.  Running Firefox (Version 52.0a2 (2016-12-10) (64-bit)) on the same system does not exhibit this behaviour.

I'm using jquery 2.2.1 with UI, tablesorter, datetimeentr, input mask, multiple and jqwidgets

I haven't modified the CSS...This is just the dialog set-up.

```js
$("#login").dialog({
  modal: true,
  draggable: true,
  resizable: false,
  position: {
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window
  },
  show: "blind",
  hide: "blind",
  height: 208,
  width: 204,
  dialogClass: "ui-dialog-osx",
  buttons: {
    "Login": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
      $("#frmlogin").submit();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-osx ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="about" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="height: auto; width: 264px; top: 368px; left: 535px; display: block;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">About</span><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button></div><div id="about" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 126px;">
<p style="text-align:center;line-height:20px;">
Timekeeper, Version 2.0<br>
from <strong>Syberdyne Systems Ltd</strong><br>
licensed to </p><div id="cmpyname" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding:0 0 0 0;margin:0 0 0 0;">Syberdyne Systems Ltd.</div>    
   <p></p> 
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span></button></div></div></div>
```

After the edit, the same code doesn't exhibit the problem, but it does on my system...it has to be CSS related.

[11/12/2016 Edit] Using the Safari web-inspector I removed all the CSS and left just 'jquery-ui-min.css', I still get the lines through the dialogs:

[image]

Comment: Add your relevant code please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, done

Comment: Hey, concerning the edit, if you think the issue is caused by CSS, you should add the relevant CSS to the question. Have you tried removing stylesheets from your page ?

Comment: I will try removing tomorrow getting late now

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4114297/paulgv, tried this, still leaving just the jquery css, it still does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was in the CSS class definition:

```
    .ui-widget-content {
      border: 1px solid #777;
      background: #eee url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png") repeat-x;
      color: #333
    }
```

Changing it to:

```
    .ui-widget-content {
      border: 1px solid #777;
      background: #eee repeat-x;
      color: #333
    }
```

Fixed the problem.

Comment: So, this removes the line, but also the soft gradient from white to grey in the background. The line seems to be the lower edge of this gradient. Is removing the gradient altogether still the only solution?